# App-published actions not shown in news feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

I have a mobile app with custom open graph action and object. I already have the action approved (active) and tried publishing it a few times. These actions show up in activity log and on timeline, but not in my news feed. How can I make them show up on news feed/ticker too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I publish Open Graph Actions from my facebook app to a user's news feed in addition to their timeline?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9502163/can-i-publish-open-graph-actions-from-my-facebook-app-to-a-users-news-feed-in-a)

Comment: So I guess what I see is a normal behavior?

Comment: Correct, not all actions get a news feed story; if they did, there'd be too many news feed stories

Comment: Thanks, I guess this question can be closed as duplicate.